# Avoid duplication in CDC / Ongoing Replication for AWS DMS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, dms

I have performed a DMS task with ongoing replication. The issue I'm facing is that if a perticular row in updated 3 times I only want its last state but what I'm getting is all the 3 records. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

No - this is by design of DMS. It captures transaction logs and ships each change to defined target endpoints. If you have updated a record 3 times, it equates to 3 transactions. 
If you define the target as an S3 bucket, and you made you should see 3 files each with that transaction version.